# Laptop started but not loaded(EFI)

Tags: windows, uefi, bootloader, kali-linux

I install Kali Linux on my laptop MSI and in Windows I with bcdedit change bootmgr from /HardVolume.../windows.efi to /HardVolume.../linux.efi. And after rebooting I have logo MSI and nothing!!!  I press all <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>. I can't go to BIOS, I can't go to recovery by Windows 10 and I can't go to boot menu. In BIOS boot I had USB on first place and I can't loaded from USB. Just what I can... Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and reload the laptop. But if I press Power button on 5-15 seconds and start laptop again then keyboard lights are activating. What I can do?

Comment: If your laptop has an FN key you should try pressing it while holding F2 to get into UEFI. Windows BCD will not work this way and this is probably a bad idea in general. Either use GRUB or EFIstub for loading Linux. If you can get into UEFI then try to load Kali and await further instruction. You could also use a windows repair CD to fix BCD but probably easier to just get linux working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed accumulator and then removed CMOS for reset BIOS (but on MSI ge62 has the button for reset). Then I go to recovery by Windows 10 and in command line(cmd) I write "bootrec /FixMbr" and "bootrec /FixBoot". And I return path of {bootmgr} used bcdedit.